# Laravel Eloquent Relationships -- equivalent of MYSQL "join"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

It seems that in all that Laravel Eloquent relationships can do, it isn't possible to have it add an `INNER JOIN` clause. Am I correct in that? `whereHas` clauses add a `WHERE EXISTS` subquery, and `with` clauses preform "eager loading" that just loads the relationship in separate queries.

Obviously, there are a lot of cases where an `INNER JOIN` is going to be *way* more efficient than running a bunch of queries, so I have written a `join` clause for these queries.

1. Is it possible to use an eloquent relationship to define a `join` clause so that I don't have to rewrite the same join query every time I use the 2 tables together?
2. If not, why? It seems like joining 2 tables that are related would be something that should be standardized. I can't really see how adding a subquery like `WHERE EXISTS` would be a suitable substitute. (according to my tests, it generates **much slower** queries....)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

Comment: @Jackowski -- Thanks for the quick response. I am aware that you can manually add a `join` clause to every query that needs it. My question here is whether it is possible to define a relationship in a Laravel "model", and then reference that to include the `join` clause automatically, rather than typing it manually every time. (And if it isn't possible, I was wondering why that is not standard in Laravel, since it seems like it should be a standard way to grab data from related tables.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Jackowski pointed out, [joins can be performed using the query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins)

As to why the Laravel framework uses multiple queries vs joins (e.g. to load relationships), it's because joins in general are expensive because of the following:

1. Joins generally invoke a cartesian product and are therefore slow. Of course, this also depends on your indices and how the query optimizer works
2. Joins are not scalable: why? Joins are very very inefficient on sharded databases / table  partitions. As soon as you start scaling to multiple servers and shard your DB, you would need to remove all joins in your code. A great example is Pinterest - as they scaled, [they had to remove all joins for sharding](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/4/15/scaling-pinterest-from-0-to-10s-of-billions-of-page-views-a.html)

Of course, joins can still be done using the query builder but Laravel forces the question to the developer: do you really need joins or is there another way?

Disclaimer: generalities are dangerous and you should always consider your specific use case